# No DTD found when it is found. It's right there

Tags: vb.net, dtd, xml

Using this code:

```
Dim stream As Stream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
        AddHandler settings.ValidationEventHandler, AddressOf ValidationCallBack
        Dim r As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings, "R:\ftproot\graphics\reference\onix-international.dtd") '" & dtdDocument)
```

The path is correct. oni-international.dtd is a DTD file. Yet when I run the above code I get this error:

No DTD found.

Despite the fact it's staring you right in the face. My validation code works perfectly for other DTD files. Might it be that the DTD file itself is invalid? How would I check?

Comment: `onix-international.dtd` or `oni-international.dtd`?  In your posted code it's `onix`, in your explanation it's `oni` - typo in the question, or typo in the code?

Comment: In the question. The code is correct.